# Can darker color schemes be applied to Visual Studio 2010!

Tags: visual-studio-2010, razor, editor

I am trying to find a good styler (a scheme for Visual Studio 2010 editor) just like these ones at:

http://studiostyl.es/

But I don't know if it is working for .cshtml files:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
}

@section HeadTitle
{
    My Site
}

@section MainContent
{   
    <div id="mainLeft">
        <h1>My Site</h1>
        @{ Html.RenderAction("History", "History");}
    </div>

    <div id="sideRight">
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Themes that support `.cshtml` files (for the Razor view engine) are tagged as such: http://studiostyl.es/schemes/supporting/razor

There are at least 30 dark schemes on that page...